# Polynomials that define a projective variety

Tags: projective-space, projective-varieties

Let $ L \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ be a linear subspace of dimension $ n-1 $, be $ X \subset L $ irreducible projective subvariety and $ y_0 \in \mathbb{P}^n - L $. $ \forall x \in X $ let's consider $ L_x $ the line between $ x $ and $ y_0 $, consider the set $$ Y = \cup_{x \in X} L_x $$ Show that $ Y $ is irreducible projective variety and $ dimY = dimX + 1 $

*In this case, the linear subspace of a projective refers to:
Consider $ V \subset K^{n + 1} $ linear subspace of dimension $ n $, then $ \mathbb{P}(V) \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ is linear subspace of dimension $ n-1 $*

I already showed that it is irreducible, I need to calculate what are the equations that define it as a variety, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Choose coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^n$ so that $L=(x_n=0)$ and $y_0=(0:0:\dots:0:1)$.  The defining equations of $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ then gives ...

Comment: If $X=Z(F_1,...,F_r)$ with $F_i \in K[x_0,...,x_{n-1}]$ homogeneus, because $X \subset x_n=0$, I would like to "homogenize" $ F_i $ to define $ Y $, but $ F_i $ is already homogenous

Comment: So what is $Z(F_1,\dots,F_r)\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ (not it is $n$ not $n-1$)?

Comment: Really sorry, I think I did not understand the question you asked @user10354138